# bloc state variable access

Tags: flutter, bloc

Bit confused with Bloc.
I would like to know why I have to use final state = this.state while trying to get access to the list in the bloc file;
and then use state to get access to state.todoList.
Why can't I just use this.state or state directly to access the todoList.

Event file :

```
sealed class TodoEvent extends Equatable {
  const TodoEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class AddToDo extends TodoEvent {
  final ToDo todo;

  const AddToDo({required this.todo});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [todo];
}
```

Bloc file :

```
class TodoBloc extends Bloc<TodoEvent, TodoState> {
 TodoBloc() : super(const TodoInitial(todoList: [])) {
   on<AddToDo>(_addToDo);
 }

 void _addToDo(
   AddToDo event,
   Emitter<TodoState> emit,
 ) {
   emit(TodoLoading());
   try {
     final state = this.state;
     if (state is TodoLoaded) {
       emit(TodoLoaded(todoList: [event.todo, ...state.todoList]));
     }
   } catch (e) {
     emit(TodoError(error: e.toString()));
   }
 }
```

Comment: You are instantiating a local variable with the same name as the upper scope variable, each scope has its own stack of variables, so to access the upper scope you need to pass some reference to the interpreter/compiler to access the other variable with the same name, if Otherwise, it will try to access the local variable that you tried to create, which should generate an error.